# Verification of client executable by server

Tags: ssl, tcp, client

Is it possible -by a server- to verify that a client executable is not modified?
Something along the lines of a digital signature but one that can be verified over a network?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: It depends on what level of security you need. There is no perfect way.

Comment: My search skills failed me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456658/validating-client-binaries-in-client-server-handshake

Thanks

Comment: The Trusted Computing Group is trying to build a system for it in hardware. It protects the bootloader, operating system, and any programs which choose to use it through the operating system. It also can provide validation over a network by use of asymmetric cryptography. It is not widely enabled yet.